# Connecting QGIS to Oracle?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, mac, oracle-dbms

I am using QGIS 3.8 MacOS.

I know that prior releases of QGIS (2.x releases) did not include drivers to connect to Oracle databases, and one would need to compile QGIS themselves with the proper Oracle drivers included if they needed to connect to Oracle.

Now that there are "Official All-in-one, signed installers" for macOS have Oracle drivers been included (or are they not allowed due to licensing or some other reason)?

Changing our corporate culture to think of using QGIS before reaching for an Esri license is very challenging if we cannot connect to our spatial databases from all platforms.